# Optimizing PHP script

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

I have a working script that selects image fields in all tables and empty their values if the physical file doesnt exist.

```
$query1 = "SELECT table_name,column_name
           FROM information_schema.columns
           WHERE table_schema='schemaname' AND column_name like '%image%' or column_name='video'";

$result1 = mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error() . " -- " . $query1);

while($row1 = mysql_fetch_row($result1)){
    if (!strpos($row1[0],'backup') > 0){
            $sql = "Select COLUMN_NAME FROM information_schema.columns WHERE TABLE_NAME = '".$row1[0]."' AND EXTRA = 'auto_increment'";
            $resultcol = mysql_query($sql);
            $rowcol = mysql_fetch_row($resultcol);

    $query2 = "SELECT " . $row1[1] . ", " .$rowcol[0] . "
               FROM " . $row1[0] . "
               WHERE " . $row1[1] . " != '' AND " . $row1[1] . " IS NOT NULL
               ";
echo $query2 . "<br>";  
    $result2 = mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error() . " -- " . $query2);

    while ($rowdb =  mysql_fetch_row($result2)){

        if (!strpos($rowdb[0],'facebook') > 0 && !file_exists($img_root.'/'.$rowdb[0])){


            $sql = "UPDATE ".$row1[0]." SET ". $row1[1] . " = '' WHERE " . $rowcol[0]. "= ".$rowdb[1];
            echo $sql . "<br><br>";
            $delete_count++;
            //mysql_query("UPDATE ".$row1[0]." SET ". $row1[1] . " = '' WHERE id = ".$row1["id"]);
        }
    }
    }
}
```

The script is working fine, but it takes time though, I was wondering if there is a smarter way (more optimized) to get the same function ? Thanks

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You can combine the first two queries into a single query with a JOIN.

Comment: You shouldn't be using mysql_* functions any more, they're deprecated

Answer (score 0):

You have several options.

The first, and IMHO the best option - is to use an ORM - 
I recommend Idiorm, Doctrine, or Propel.

Then, you would use something like (in idiorm) `fetch_all` and loop through that, instead of through the `mysql_fetch_row()`

Second, you should switch to `mysqli` -- the functions you are using are deprecated in PHP5.5

Third -- you could just use either `mysql_fetch_array` or `mysql_fetch_all` (I'm not sure, but I would be on the latter)

The key thing here is:

Do not loop mysql functions.

Answer (score 0):

Performance wise the problem is that you are looping through a result set, and performing queries for each row.

However with your output it is difficult to eliminate this. Otherwise you might be able to do the whole script in a single SQL statement.

Minimal clean up to just remove one of the selects:-

```
<?php

$query1 = "SELECT a.table_name, a.column_name, b.COLUMN_NAME AS auto_inc_col
           FROM information_schema.columns a
           INNER JOIN information_schema.columns b
           ON a.table_name = b.table_name AND b.EXTRA = 'auto_increment'
           WHERE table_schema='schemaname' AND column_name like '%image%' or column_name='video'";

$result1 = mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error() . " -- " . $query1);

while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1))
{
    if (!strpos($row1['table_name'],'backup') > 0)
    {
        $query2 = "SELECT " . $row1['column_name'] . ", " .$row1['auto_inc_col'] . "
                   FROM " . $row1['table_name'] . "
                   WHERE " . $row1['column_name'] . " != '' AND " . $row1['column_name'] . " IS NOT NULL
                   ";
        echo $query2 . "<br>";  
        $result2 = mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error() . " -- " . $query2);

        while ($rowdb =  mysql_fetch_row($result2))
        {
            if (!strpos($rowdb[0],'facebook') > 0 && !file_exists($img_root.'/'.$rowdb[0]))
            {
                $sql = "UPDATE ".$row1['table_name']." SET ". $row1['column_name'] . " = '' WHERE " . $row1['auto_inc_col']. "= ".$rowdb[1];
                echo $sql . "<br><br>";
                $delete_count++;
                //mysql_query("UPDATE ".$row1['table_name']." SET ". $row1['column_name'] . " = '' WHERE id = ".$row1["id"]);
            }
        }
    }
}

?>
```